# How to use getStaticProps in combination with useReducer and useContext

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am converting a React app to a NextJS app and cannot figure out how to use the props of `getStaticProps` into the initial state of my reducer inside my context.

In my current setup, my **AppContext** looks like this:

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";
import { initialState, appReducer } from "../reducers/appReducer";

const AppContext = createContext(); 

const AppContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(appReducer, initialState);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { AppContext, AppContextProvider };
```

The I have my **appReducer** as follows:

```
export const initialState = {
   example: null,
   anotherExample: []
};

export const AppReducer = (state, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case "example_action":
      return {...state, example: payload.example }
  }
  default:
    return state;
}
```

What I do not understand is how I can get the props of `getStaticProps` in the initial state of my reducer (since my whole application is based on this context with reducer).

**ExamplePage (pages/example-page.js)**

```
export default function ExamplePage({ data }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(appReducer, {
    ...initialState,
    example: data.example
  });
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
      <div>...</div> // Rest of my application
    <AppContext.Provider>
  );
}

export export async function getStaticProps() {
  const { data } = // Fetching my data ....
  return {
    props: {
      data: data,
    },
  };
}
```

What I tried to do is move the reducer out of the AppContext, so I can pass the props from `getStaticProps` to it, but then I cannot use the AppContext including my reducer anymore in other places in my application. Or should I create my context like this:

**AppContext.js**

```
import { createContext } from "react";
const AppContext = createContext();

// Don't create my provider here, do it in ExamplePage?

export default AppContext;
```

And import this everywhere I want to use this context and create the provider inside my ExamplePage only?

I have the feeling I do not understand the concept of context, reducer with NextJS, is that true?

Comment: I'd recommend looking into [`next-redux-wrapper`](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper). Next.js also provides an example with it: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux-wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand what exactly you want to achieve, but I think you're using contexts in the wrong place.

If, as I understand it, your whole React application was wrapped in a Context Provider, and you want to repeat this in nextjs, the `_app.js` file is best suited for this. This is a special file in nextjs, more about it here: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app, if you don't have it, you need to create it in the `pages` folder.

In your case it will be something like this:

```
// ./pages/_app.js

const AppContext = createContext();

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(appReducer, initialState);
  return(
    <AppContext.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </AppContext.Provider>
   )
}
```

The `_app.js` is a special file in nextjs, all pages of your site will be wrapped in it, you can use this for your global states, they will not be reset when the user navigates through the pages of the site.

`getStaticProps` is designed for a completely different purpose, `getStaticProps` is designed to process data for a specific page, and not for all pages of the site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I gave a little bit wrong example because the context is not meant for the whole application, but a specific section only. I need the props from getStaticProps in my context and on the first render of the page. Is that possible?